# XP-PEN Artist 12 Pro Multiple Displays

Tags: hdmi, tablet, wacom, stylus

I am trying to install an XP-PEN Artist 12 Pro on Ubuntu. When I use the official XP-PEN driver the pen cursor stops moving and the XP-PEN tablet won't open. When uninstalled I have pen cursor movement and pressure sensitivity on the screen.
I have the tablet connected via an HDMI splitter along my main screen. Also, I have connected an additional of 4 other screens. All with AMD® Radeon (tm) rx 460 graphics. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.
I use this command "xinput map-to-output 9 HDMI-A-0" and the pen/stylus to set the tablet screen to my main HDMI monitor which is mirrored to the tablet, however the movement is not the correct one; when moving to the right instead it goes up, instead of down to the left, instead of up it goes to the right, and instead of down it goes to the left. How can I put the correct movement, because the pressure sensitivity and the display are working correctly, so the movement would be the only issue I have. I have already contacted XP-PEN support but it doesn't seem they can help.

I also used this command: xsetwacom --set "UGTABLET 11.6 inch PenDisplay stylus" MapToOutput 1920x1080+0+0
and it worked for a while but after a restart it wouldn't work even after I used this same command after the one mentioned above: xinput map-to-output 9 HDMI-A-0.

So the only issue would be the stylus/pen cursor movement so that I can have this drawing tablet in working condition. I have googled it but can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, and that it could help them with a similar problem. I managed to set the correct cursor direction of the XP-PEN Tablet. I used these commands:

1. xsetwacom --set "UGTABLET 11.6 inch PenDisplay stylus" MapToOutput 1920x1080+1050+768 ***I got this specific info and resolution by using xrandr"***
2. xsetwacom --set 9 Rotate ccw
3. xsetwacom --set 9  Area 0 32767 32767 0 ***I got the original Area by using "xsetwacom --get 9" the 9 is the ID device***

Now my tablet has the correct movement, the sensitive pressure is native to the Linux kernel I believe as it works. Now I have to figure out a way to set up the 8 buttons of the drawing tablet.